# Filter, sort and map array based on condition in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, filter

My data is following

```
  data=[
{
id: 1,
name: 'John Doe',
contacts: 'john.doe@gmail.com',
accepted: true
},
{
id: 2,
name: 'Jane Doe',
contacts: 'jane.doe@gmail.com',
accepted: false
},

]
```

I want to filter (if filterKey variable is not empty/null) and sort(if sortKey variable is not empty/null). I can do it with some if/then but is there a better way?

```
 let computedList = data
 if(filterKey) {
      computedList = data.filter(item => item.name.includes(filterKey))
 }  
 if(sortKey) {
      computedList = data.sort(...)
 }
 computedList.map(item => <div>item.name</div>)
```

Comment: Where do `filterKey` and `sortKey` come from?

Comment: Your solution doesn't work if both `filterKey` and `sortKey` are present, it always sorts the `data` not the result of the filter.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I meant to use `computedList` in sortKey block. `filterKey` and `sortKey` come externally (from React props).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can do it with some if/then but is there a better way?

Not really, no. That's the cleanest, clearest way, there's really no need for an alternative unless you're working in certain programming styles (like functional programming), which you don't appear to be. But you want to use `computedList`, not `data`, in the `sort` statement (in case you've filtered). And of course you need to do something with the return value of `map`.

---

Side note: `sort` is in-place, so no need for the assignment, and if you aren't the owner of the array `data` points to, you may want to clone first if you aren't filtering. E.g.:

```
let computedList = filterKey ? data.filter(item => item.name.includes(filterKey)) : data.slice();
if (sortKey) {
    computedList.sort(/*...*/);
}
let result = computedList.map(item => <div>item.name</div>);
```

or perhaps

```
let computedList = data;
if (filterKey) {
    computedList = computedList.filter(item => item.name.includes(filterKey));
}
if (sortKey) {
    if (!filterKey) {
        computedList = computedList.slice();
    }
    computedList.sort(/*...*/);
}
let result = computedList.map(item => <div>item.name</div>);
```

...to avoid making the copy unless you need to.

Comment: Yes, I meant to use computedList in sortKey block

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai: Reading your deleted answer, though, I can see several issues if that's helpful: It always makes copies of the array, even if it doesn't need to; it calls `String#includes` repeatedly with `undefined/""/null` in the case where `filterKey` is falsy; it calls `sort` when there's no need to sort, and falsely claims all the entries are equal in that case (which breaks the sort callback contract). So ... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong with an `if/else` now and then. However, you can "hide" the `if`s using functions' composition:

```js
const data = [ 
  {id: 1, name: 'John Doe', contacts: 'john.doe@gmail.com', accepted: true},
  {id: 2, name: 'Jane Doe', contacts: 'jane.doe@gmail.com', accepted: false},
  {id: 3, name: 'Jane J', contacts: 'jane.doe@gmail.com', accepted: false}
];

const filter = (data, filterKey) => filterKey ? data.filter(item => item.name.includes(filterKey)) : data

const sort = (data, sortKey) => sortKey ? [...data].sort((a, b) => a[sortKey] > b[sortKey]) : data

const filterKey = 'Doe'
const sortKey = 'name'
const computedList = sort(filter(data, filterKey), sortKey)
      // .map(item => <div>item.name</div>) // removed for the demo
console.log(computedList);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```